# Shouldn't "1 answers/votes/views" be "1 answer/vote/view"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, plurals

Shouldn't this grammar issue be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it should. [Good luck with that...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22giant+s%22)

Comment: @Ben Thanks, I'll battle it out with Jeff over a game of Scrabble.

Comment: Yep, it will be fixed. By translating all the labels to Japanese (which doesn't distinguish between singular/plural).

Comment: @SPArchaeologist, we would have to add [counter words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word), though. That will possibly make things even more complicated :)

Comment: What's interesting is not the lack of correct plural handling, but the fact that it is *inconsistent*. It says "1 answers" on the "Top Questions" page, but if you browse "All Questions", it actually says "1 answer".

Comment: @CodyGray Really? I've never noticed that.

Comment: Related: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: "Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S" - Jeff Atwood

Answer (score 7):

Instead of reading it as "1 answers", I make an effort to read it as "answers: 1". Then me and my OCD can get on with our day.

Comment: My OCD thinks that "answers:"
 should be on top.

Comment: sorry for being noob here. But what is OCD?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder

Comment: @TomHart, If I actually had OCD I think that URL might trigger a twitching fit. `O-C_D`

Answer (score 1):

> ## Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S

— [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/163250)

<sub>[It's a tradition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/163250).</sub>